# React/Redux: API calls return 401 after being redirected on successful login

Tags: reactjs, redux

My code is supposed to redirect the user from the `/login` route to `/dashboard` on successful login, and it does that fine with `history.push('/dashboard')`. However, after redirection, inside the dashboard, the AJAX API calls return 401, which work fine after a refresh.

My index.js file looks like this:

```
const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk))

const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
if (token) {
    const decodedToken = jwt_decode(token)
    if (decodedToken.user) store.dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: decodedToken.user })
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

This is my actions.js file:

```
export const loginUser = (email, password, history) => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post(`https://ms-workit.herokuapp.com/api/auth/login`, { email, password })
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data.user })
        localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token)
        return history.push('/dashboard')
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}
```

Anything I am doing wrong here? Basically what I want is to not require a refresh for API calls to work, after being redirected to dashboard from the login screen.

For the record, I am using Express, Passport.js, Mongo for my backend.

React novice here so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you should consider using [middlewares](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware) and move navigation and fetching to middleware effects

Comment: @Rostyslav can you elaborate please? Not really sure if I understand.

Comment: head over to egghead.io and dive through a handful of tutorials. At this point you're doing a few things that are going to cause you trouble in the future.. 1: mixing logic, 2: not using a middleware (redux thunk), 3: routing inside an action vs responding to an incoming state change... you'll just run into more problems..